# creating mview containing pl/sql definitions in with clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

How to use pl sql definitions in with clause while creating mview?

An explanation with example would really help.

Also I have tried the following queries and I have faced some errors.

```
create table tab1
(
    fname varchar2(15) ,
    lname varchar2(15)
);


create or replace type user_data_type as object (val1 varchar2(20),val2 varchar2(20));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE Function get_fname_lname(n in varchar2)
RETURN user_data_type as
name user_data_type;
cursor buffer_cur is
select fname,lname from tab1 where fname=n;
BEGIN
    name := new user_data_type(null,null);
    OPEN buffer_cur;
    fetch buffer_cur into name.val1,name.val2;

    close buffer_cur;
    return name;
End;
/
select * from tab1;
select get_fname_lname(fname).val1  fname,get_fname_lname(fname).val2 from tab1;

drop materialized view mv1;
create materialized view mv1
with names as
(select get_fname_lname(fname).val1 fname,get_fname_lname(fname).val2 lname  from    tab1)
select fname,lname from names;
select * from mv1;
```

I have seen this error:

```
Error while creating mview:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Can some one point me out what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this while creating view , since recursive views are not supported in oracle.
By using with clause you are already creating an inline view and for that view you are trying to create a materialised view which is not supported in oracle

```
create materialized view mv1
 as
 select fname,lname from
(select get_fname_lname(fname).val1 fname,get_fname_lname(fname).val2 lname 
 from    tab1);
```

Comment: Thanks.That helps..Can you give me some sample example for my first question.

Comment: @starkk92 - You want samples to create materialised view? You should not use with clause while creating view since it causes view within view